# GridView does not display correcty sorted Data when i click column

Tags: vb.net, gridview-sorting

Date column does not display in sorted in GridView using vb.net.  In sql server the select query is returning records in sorted manner or in order by.  But for some reason GridView does not display properly. it goes to an event preRenderComplete then it binds automatically

Protected Sub Page_PreRenderComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRenderComplete
        'Force the selections made in page_load to be shown in the gridview by causing a postback

```
    GridView1.DataBind()


    If GridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        'this is not counting correctly disable until i get it figured out
        '' lblMsg.Text = GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString + " Referrals"
    Else
        lblMsg.Text() = "No referrals to be processed"
    End If

    'Turn off the Background Contolls
    'If Not IsPostBack Then PanelBackendControls.Visible = False


End Sub
```

## End Region

_
        Public Shared Function A02WF01_AdminView(ByVal strUserID As String, ByVal strTestMode As String, ByVal strSearchFieldValue As String, ByVal strDate As String) As DataTable
        Dim sel As String

```
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(WF01ConnectionString)
    If strSearchFieldValue <> "" And strTestMode = "ON" Then
        sel = "SELECT DISTINCT Since, WorkFlow_Step, "
        sel = sel & " Started_By, Client_FullName, Product_Desc, "
        sel = sel & " Branch_List, Event_AssignedID, DaysElapsed, Status,Instance_ID,Seq_ID,Form_Code "


        sel = sel & " FROM A02W01ViewAllTest "

        Dim WhereClause As String
        Dim OrderClause As String

        WhereClause = " WHERE ( Event_IsLatest = 1)"
        If strUserID <> "Admin" Then

        End If
        'WhereClause = WhereClause + " AND WF_Start_UserID like " + "'" + strUserID + "')"
        WhereClause = WhereClause + " And( Started_By Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%'"
        WhereClause = WhereClause + " OR Client_FullName Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%'"
        'WhereClause = WhereClause + " OR FullName Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%'"
        WhereClause = WhereClause + " OR Product_Desc Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%'"
        WhereClause = WhereClause + " OR Branch_List Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%'"
        WhereClause = WhereClause + " OR DaysElapsed Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%')"
        'WhereClause = WhereClause + " OR Form_Code Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%')"




        OrderClause = " ORDER BY Since DESC"

        sel = sel + WhereClause + OrderClause
    ElseIf strSearchFieldValue <> "" And strTestMode <> "ON" Then
        sel = "SELECT DISTINCT Since, WorkFlow_Step, "
        sel = sel & " Started_By, Client_FullName, Product_Desc, "
        sel = sel & " Branch_List, Event_AssignedID, DaysElapsed, Status "


        sel = sel & " FROM A02W01ViewAll "

        Dim WhereClause As String
        Dim OrderClause As String

        WhereClause = " WHERE ( Event_IsLatest = 1)"
        If strUserID <> "Admin" Then

        End If
        'WhereClause = WhereClause + " AND WF_Start_UserID like " + "'" + strUserID + "')"
        WhereClause = WhereClause + " AND( Started_By Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%'"
        WhereClause = WhereClause + " OR Client_FullName Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%'"
        'WhereClause = WhereClause + " OR Client_LastName Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%'"
        WhereClause = WhereClause + " OR Product_Desc Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%'"
        WhereClause = WhereClause + " OR Branch_List Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%'"
        WhereClause = WhereClause + " OR DaysElapsed Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%'))"
        'WhereClause = WhereClause + " OR Form_Code Like " + "'%" + strSearchFieldValue + "%'))"




        OrderClause = " ORDER BY Since DESC"

        sel = sel + WhereClause + OrderClause

    End If

    If strTestMode <> "ON" And strSearchFieldValue = "" Then

        sel = "SELECT DISTINCT Since, WorkFlow_Step, "
        sel = sel & " Started_By, Client_LastName, Client_FullName, Product_Desc, "
        sel = sel & " Branch_List, Event_AssignedID, DaysElapsed, Status "


        sel = sel & " FROM A02W01ViewAll "

        Dim WhereClause As String
        Dim OrderClause As String

        WhereClause = " WHERE Event_IsLatest = 1"
        'WhereClause = WhereClause + " AND (Event_IsLatest = 1) "

        OrderClause = " ORDER BY Since DESC"

        sel = sel + WhereClause + OrderClause
    Else


        If strSearchFieldValue = "" And strTestMode = "ON" And strDate = "" Then
            sel = "SELECT DISTINCT Since, WorkFlow_Step, "
            sel = sel & " Started_By, Client_FullName, Product_Desc, "
            sel = sel & " Branch_List, Event_AssignedID, DaysElapsed, Status, Instance_ID,Seq_ID,Form_Code "


            sel = sel & " FROM A02W01ViewAllTest "

            Dim WhereClause As String
            Dim OrderClause As String

            WhereClause = " WHERE Event_IsLatest = 1"
            'Display everything for Admin
            ' Comment below code
            'If strUserID <> "Admin" Then WhereClause = WhereClause + " AND WF_Start_UserID like " + "'" + strUserID + "'"


            OrderClause = " ORDER BY Since DESC"

            sel = sel + WhereClause + OrderClause
        ElseIf strSearchFieldValue = "" And strTestMode = "ON" And strDate <> "" Then
            sel = ""
            sel = sel & "SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT Since, WorkFlow_Step, "
            sel = sel & "Started_By, Client_Fullname, Product_Desc, "
            sel = sel & "Branch_List, Event_AssignedID, DaysElapsed, Status, "
            sel = sel & "Instance_ID, Seq_ID, Form_Code "


            sel = sel & " FROM A02W01ViewDistinct "

            Dim WhereClause As String
            Dim OrderClause As String

            WhereClause = " WHERE Event_IsLatest = 1"
            'Display everything for Admin
            ' Comment below code
            'If strUserID <> "Admin" Then WhereClause = WhereClause + " AND WF_Start_UserID like " + "'" + strUserID + "'"


            OrderClause = " ORDER BY YEAR(Since) DESC, MONTH(Since) DESC, DAY(Since) DESC"

            sel = sel + WhereClause + OrderClause
        End If



    End If

    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sel, conn)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

    Try
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(ds, "odsA02_Tracking")
        conn.Close()
    Catch e As SqlException
        WFClassLib.PageError()
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

    If ds.Tables("odsA02_Tracking") IsNot Nothing Then _
      Return ds.Tables("odsA02_Tracking")

    'Return ds
    'If ds.Tables("odsA02_Tracking") Is Nothing Then

    Return Nothing
    'End If







End Function
```

BorderStyle="Outset" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="odsA02_Tracking"
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Vertical" Style="border-right: #0000ff thin solid;
            table-layout: auto; border-top: #0000ff thin solid; font-size: x-small; border-left: #0000ff thin solid;
            border-bottom: #0000ff thin solid; font-family: Arial; border-collapse: separate" Font-Size="Small" PageSize="30">

```
        <Columns>
         <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />

            <asp:boundfield datafield="Since" HeaderText="Submit Date" ReadOnly=True SortExpression="Since" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Started_By" HeaderText="Submitted By" SortExpression="Started_By" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Client_FullName" HeaderText="Client Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Client_FullName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Product_Desc" HeaderText="Product" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Product_Desc" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Branch_List" HeaderText="Branch" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Branch_List" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Event_AssignedID" HeaderText="Assigned To" ReadOnly="True"
                SortExpression="Event_AssignedID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DaysElapsed" HeaderText="Days Open" ReadOnly="True"  SortExpression="DaysElapsed" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" /> 
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID=hdnInstanceID Value='<%#Eval("Instance_ID") %>' runat=server>
            </asp:HiddenField>
             </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID=hdnSeqID Value='<%#Eval("Seq_ID") %>' runat=server/>                 
            </ItemTemplate>             

            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID=hdnFormCode Value='<%#Eval("Form_Code") %>' runat=server/>                 
            </ItemTemplate>             

            </asp:TemplateField>



        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Style="font-size: small; color: red; font-family: Arial"
        Width="525px" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnReturn" runat="server" Text="Return" /><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lbltxtUserID" runat="server" Text="txtUserID" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserID" runat="server" Visible="False" Width="226px"></asp:TextBox><br />
     <asp:Label ID="label4" runat="server" Text="TestModeOn" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TestModeOn" runat="server"  Visible="False" Width="226px"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblSearchUserEntered" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="searchText" ></asp:Label> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="searchText" runat="server" Visible="False" Width ="226px" ></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="txtInstance_ID" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInstance_ID" runat="server" Visible="False" Width="226px"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="txtSeq_ID" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSeq_ID" runat="server" Visible="False" Width="226px"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="txtForm_Code" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtForm_Code" runat="server" Visible="False" Width="226px"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblSince" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Since" ></asp:Label> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="SortSince" runat="server" Visible="False" Width ="226px" ></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsA02_Tracking" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
        SelectMethod="A02WF01_AdminView" TypeName="WFA02DataObjects">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtUserID" Name="strUserID" PropertyName="Text"
                Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TestModeOn" Name="strTestMode" PropertyName="Text"
                Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="searchText" Name="strSearchFieldValue" PropertyName="Text"
                Type="String" />
                 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SortSince" Name="strDate" PropertyName="Text"
                Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

</div>
</form>
```